# Getting Empty Emails From PHP & HTML Contact Form

Tags: php, html, email

I am a student of Web Designing and Development trying to make a website. I have created Contact form for a website using php and html. I am new to php so I don't know anything about it. I have copy a code from website, by which I am getting an E-mail but empty [ without information which I have enter on website contact form ].
Here is my HTML code [File Name: contact.html]:-

```
 <div class="login-w3l">    
            <div class="top-img-agileits-w3layouts">
                <h2 class="sub-head-w3-agileits">Contact Us</h2>
                <p>Fillout the form below !</p>
                <div class="login-form">    
                <form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="First Name" required="" />
                    <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Last Name" required="" />
                    <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required="" />
                    <input type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject" required="" />
                    <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </form> 
            </div>
            </div>          


                </div> 
-----End of HTML-----
```

Here is my PHP code [File name: handler.php]:-

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST ['first name'];
$last_name = $_POST ['last name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST ['email'];
$message = $_POST ['message'];

$email_from = 'info@wms-wms-wms.tk';

$email_subject = "WMS Contact form";

$email_body = "User First Name :  $first_name \n".
                                        "User Last Name :  $last_name \n".
                                                "User Email :  $visitor_email \n ".
                                                        "User Message : $message \n";

 $to = "wms-wms-wms@outlook.sa";   

 $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

 $headers .= "Reply To: $visitor_email \r\n";


 mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

 header("Location: contact.html");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to format your form elements appropriately.  Adding unique `name` and `id` attributes are pertinent to form submission.  So, I updated your name and id elements to match what your php script is looking for.

```
<div class="login-w3l">
    <div class="top-img-agileits-w3layouts">
        <h2 class="sub-head-w3-agileits">Contact Us</h2>
        <p>Fillout the form below !</p>
        <div class="login-form">
            <form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required=""/>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required=""/>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required=""/>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required=""/>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that, your variables up top should now be filled with your form elements you previously filled out.

Here is your edited PHP to actually work:

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

....

?>
```

Comment: Reply To: name@hotmail.com

User First Name :   
User Last Name :   
User Email :  name@hotmail.com 
 User Message : I am testing my website
Now I am getting reply to: User email and message but not getting subject, first name and last name why?

Comment: Great, please accept as the answer if it works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to make the `name` and `id` attribute to be all lower case and with no spaces.

Also don't add spaces between `$_POST` and `[]`.

Try Using:

```
<div class="login-w3l">
    <div class="top-img-agileits-w3layouts">
        <h2 class="sub-head-w3-agileits">Contact Us</h2>
        <p>Fillout the form below !</p>
        <div class="login-form">
            <form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required=""/>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required=""/>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required=""/>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required=""/>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST['first name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_from = 'info@wms-wms-wms.tk';

$email_subject = "WMS Contact form";

$email_body = "User First Name :  $first_name \n".
              "User Last Name :  $last_name \n".
              "User Email :  $visitor_email \n ".
              "User Message : $message \n";

 $to = "wms-wms-wms@outlook.sa";   

 $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

 $headers .= "Reply To: $visitor_email \r\n";


 mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

 header("Location: contact.html");

?>
```